# DisplayAlert cancel at touch outdside

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, alert

I am creating an app in xamarin forms. I am using Display Alert to show messages with Yes/No button. But when user tap outside of the popup, it gets close. I don't want to close the popup on outside tap. It should close only after user click on Yes or No button.

How I can manage my popup so that it can not close when user tap outside of the popup in xamarin forms?

Comment: Maybe you could show it again when this happen ? what kind of results you get when the user taps outside ?

Comment: you'll have to write a custom renderer, there is **no way** to do that in XF

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit too late, but it might benefit others who come across this question.

---

This can be done pretty easily, once you know how to do it. Below is a brief step-by-step guide that should help you running.

1. Create a new Class file in the shared project, and call it **CustomYesNoBox.cs**.
2. In this file, paste the code below:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;

   using Xamarin.Forms;

   public class CustomYesNoBox
   {
       public string Text { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public List<string> Buttons { get; set; }

       public CustomYesNoBox(string title, string text, params string[] buttons)
       {
           Title = title;
           Text = text;
           Buttons = buttons.ToList();
       }

       public CustomYesNoBox(string title, string text):this(title, text, "Yes", "No")
       {
       }

       public event EventHandler<CustomYesNoBoxClosedArgs> PopupClosed;
       public void OnPopupClosed(CustomYesNoBoxClosedArgs e)
       {
           var handler = PopupClosed;
           if (handler != null)
               handler(this, e);
       }

       public void Show()
       {
           DependencyService.Get<IYesNoPopupLoader>().ShowPopup(this);
       }
   }

   public class CustomYesNoBoxClosedArgs : EventArgs
   {
       public string Button { get; set; }
   }

   public interface IYesNoPopupLoader
   {
       void ShowPopup(CustomYesNoBox reference);
   }
   ```
3. In your **Android** project folder, add a new class, and call it **YesNoPopupLoader.cs**.
4. In this file, paste the code below:

   ```
   using Android.App;
   using Android.Widget;

   using <YOUR_NAMESPACE>.Droid.Implementation;

   using Xamarin.Forms;

   [assembly: Dependency(typeof(YesNoPopupLoader))]
   namespace <YOUR_NAMESPACE>.Droid.Implementation
   {
       public class YesNoPopupLoader : IYesNoPopupLoader
       {
           public void ShowPopup(CustomYesNoBox popup)
           {
               var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Forms.Context);

               var textView = new TextView(Forms.Context) { Text = popup.Text };
               alert.SetView(textView);

               alert.SetTitle(popup.Title);

               var buttons = popup.Buttons;

               alert.SetPositiveButton(buttons[0], (senderAlert, args) =>
               {
                   popup.OnPopupClosed(new CustomYesNoBoxClosedArgs
                   {
                       Button = buttons[0]
                   });
               });

               alert.SetNegativeButton(buttons[1], (senderAlert, args) =>
               {
                   popup.OnPopupClosed(new CustomYesNoBoxClosedArgs
                   {
                       Button = buttons[1]
                   });
               });

               alert.SetCancelable(false);
               alert.Show();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. In your **iOS** project, add a new class file, and call it **YesNoPopupLoader.cs**.
6. In this file, paste the code below:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Linq;

   using <YOUR_NAMESPACE>.iOS.Implementation;

   using UIKit;

   [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(YesNoPopupLoader))]
   namespace <YOUR_NAMESPACE>.iOS.Implementation
   {
       public class YesNoPopupLoader : IYesNoPopupLoader
       {
           public void ShowPopup(CustomYesNoBox popup)
           {
               var alert = new UIAlertView
               {
                   Title = popup.Title,
                   Message = popup.Text
               };
               foreach (var b in popup.Buttons)
                   alert.AddButton(b);

               alert.Clicked += (s, args) =>
               {
                   popup.OnPopupClosed(new CustomYesNoBoxClosedArgs
                   {
                       Button = popup.Buttons.ElementAt(Convert.ToInt32(args.ButtonIndex)),
                   });
               };
               alert.Show();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
7. Go back to your shared project, and go to wherever you wish to access the message box. In this example, I have a button in my **MainPage** that will prompt this message box:

   ```
   YesNoButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
   {
       var popup = new CustomYesNoBox("Question", "Is this Android?");
       popup.PopupClosed += (o, closedArgs) =>
       {
           if (closedArgs.ButtonText == "Yes")
           {
               // Do something on positive response
           }
           else if(closedArgs.ButtonText == "No")
           {
               // Do something on negative response
           }
           else
           {
               // Unknown response. Do nothing?
           }
       };

       popup.Show();
   };
   ```

And that should be it. You can play around to create other custom message boxes (with drop down menus, text inputs, progress indicators etc) that Xamarin Forms does not offer, or customise the layout of the message box.

Answer (score 1):

You could use xlabs for the same. Using this you can show a custom popup and it won't close on background click. You can provide a close button or yes or no button to perform a task or cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

> Using AcrUserDialog could be an alternative option. https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

Answer (score 0):

I tried displaying alert until user selects positive button. I had no option but doing this because it was an urgent requirement.

```
bool input = await DisplayAlert("Sync", "Press Sync", "Sync", "Cancel");
while (!input) //Enters when clicked outside or (cancel) negative button
{
  input = await DisplayAlert("Sync Rules", "Press Sync", "Sync", "Cancel");
}
// Code when Sync is clicked
```

Will try what @Tom suggested in future.

Comment: It is not very clear - are you suggesting this as a valid solution or not?

Comment: @yakobom It is not a valid solution. It is just a workaround. I will keep displaying alert using while loop.